# textFileStream in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have the following code:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My app")
        .setMaster("local[4]")
        .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
        .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");

JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(2));

JavaDStream<String> trainingData = jssc.textFileStream("filesDirectory");

trainingData.print();

jssc.start();
jssc.awaitTermination();
```

Unfortunately, to stream any file exists in the directory I have to edit this file and rename it after starting stream context, otherwise it will not be processed.

Should I edit and rename each file to process it or there is another way to process the existing files by just edit and save them.

P.S. When I move new file to this directory, I need also to edit and rename this file to stream it!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try touching file before moving to the destination directory.
Below is what javadoc says.

- Identify whether the given `path` is a new file for the batch of `currentTime`. For it to be
- accepted, it has to pass the following criteria.
- - It must pass the user-provided file filter.
- - It must be newer than the ignore threshold. It is assumed that files older than the ignore
- threshold have already been considered or are existing files before start
- (when newFileOnly = true).
- - It must not be present in the recently selected files that this class remembers.
- - It must not be newer than the time of the batch (i.e. `currentTime` for which this
- file is being tested. This can occur if the driver was recovered, and the missing batches
- (during downtime) are being generated. In that case, a batch of time T may be generated
- at time T+x. Say x = 5. If that batch T contains file of mod time T+5, then bad things can
- happen. Let's say the selected files are remembered for 60 seconds.  At time t+61,
- the batch of time t is forgotten, and the ignore threshold is still T+1.
- The files with mod time T+5 are not remembered and cannot be ignored (since, t+5 > t+1).
- Hence they can get selected as new files again. To prevent this, files whose mod time is more
- than current batch time are not considered.
  *

Answer (score 1):

`JavaStreamingContext.textFileStream` returns a `FileInputDStream`, which is used to monitor a folder when the files in the folder are being added/updated regularly. You will get the notification after every two seconds, **only when** a new file is added/updated.

If your **intent is just to read the file**, you can rather use [SparkContext.textFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/api/core/spark/SparkContext.html).

Looking at the documentation from source code of  [JavaStreamingContext.textFileStream()](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.scala)

```
/**
   * Create a input stream that monitors a Hadoop-compatible filesystem
   * for new files and reads them as text files (using key as LongWritable, value
   * as Text and input format as TextInputFormat). Files must be written to the
   * monitored directory by "moving" them from another location within the same
   * file system. File names starting with . are ignored.
   */
```